# PHP Comparing Datetime object with current datetime and find smaller

Tags: php, datetime

I am getting `datetime` from the user through a form and the datetime entered by him, should be greater than current instance of time to be valid.

I am trying something like this

```
$input_format = 'd M Y - h:i a';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($input_format, $_POST['delivery_time']);
$now = new DateTime();
if(!$date || ($date->diff($now) > 0))
{
   $error .= '* Invalid Delivery Day/Time';
   error_log('WARNING :: Invalid Delivery Time at LINE: '.__LINE__.' in '.__FILE__.'\n',3,$logfile);
}
```

I am having problem in the comparison.I get `Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int` as error. What is the correct method to  ensure that the entered time is greater than correct instance of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) returns a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) which has the property [`invert`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.invert):

> *invert*
>
> Is 1 if the interval represents a negative time period and 0 otherwise.

---

So in place of `$date->diff($now) > 0` you can use simply `$now->diff($date)->invert`.

*(Note: this isn't strictly "greater than", it's effectively "greater than or equal to". It's easy to flip it around to be so if that's important, but it didn't seem relevant enough to warrant it.)*